# Remove data that created by Mysql into outfile?

Tags: mysql

I've created some files with into outfile command. Now I want to remove it. Is it possible? Thanks.

UPD: I want to remove those outfiles so nobody will know they existed.

Comment: You need to add more information to this question. Which data do you want to remove, the MySQL copy or the outfile? Are you looking for a secure deletion or is just deleting it sufficient?

Comment: @NeilSmithline, just deleting will be okay, since file are in access log of apache. So you understand what I mean.